# Получить из localStorage сериализованный массив

Tags: json, сериализация, localstorage, десериализация

Есть HTML форма с динамическим количеством инпутов. Добавляется к форме HTML код строк цен (`<tr>...</tr>`) выбранных юзером. В любом количестве.

Я получаю все данные формы (включая добавленные пользователем строки таблицы) в переменную:

```
var formData1 = $('#ORDERFORM').serializeArray();
```

Далее, мне нужно записать полученный результат в `localStorage`:

```
var formData = JSON.stringify(formData1);
localStorage.setItem("key", formData);
```

И получить из него данные при обращении пользователя к личному кабинету:

```
var returnFormData =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("key"));
```

И вот тут я не понимаю.
**В каком виде я получу данные из `localStorage`? Если это будет строка, то как мне получить данные из нее в массив?**

Мне требуется выводить из `localStorage` данные, ранее введенные пользователем в форму, на странице личного кабинета пользователя.

Comment: При помощи `JSON.parse ` Вы получите `json` объект. Соответственно в Вашем случае Вы должны получить массив.

Comment: Спасибо, Денис. Оформите ответом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Рад Вам помочь. Добавил ответ, может кому ещё поможет. Если Вы посчитаете необходимым дополнить или изменить ответ, Вы всегда можете сделать это нажав кнопку "править".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы выбрали абсолютно верный подход. 
При помощи `JSON.stringify(formData1)` Вы переводите массив `formData1` в строку `json`.
В случае подобного преобразования, Вы можете корректно записать данные в `localstorage` используя строку как значение, так как, при записи `localstorage` ожидает 2 параметра(ключ и значение) оба из которых должны быть строками.
Для того, чтобы провести преобразование из строки `json` Вы верно использовали `JSON.parse`.
Данный метод производит обратное преобразование объекта.

В Вашем случае Вы получите массив в параметре `returnFormData`.

Comment: Большое спасибо!